# How to start automatic application after reboot/ turn off on google tv with adb shell?

Tags: android

before i use this command to run apps
adb shell am start /

after reboot device, the apps not running automatic, it must give command " adb shell am start / " again.

any solution about this ?

Comment: you can install mdm??Have you tried that

Comment: how to install mdm on android ?

Comment: you can use headwind mdm explore about that

Comment: Can give me more detail about this ?

Comment: I mean, any other command adb shell we can try ?

Comment: Before i use this command,

Comment: Before. I use this command, 
adb shell am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName and after reboot device, apps running before not start up again. I must write that command again

Comment: you can use jenkins for that purpose

Comment: What is that jenkins ?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/jenkins_installation.htm see in this link about jenkins

Comment: I already check that link. No solution at the link :(